# how to get colors dynamically in windowsphone

Tags: windows-phone-7, colors

I used system.windows.media.color but it returns only 15 colors. In silverlight we had brushes contains more colors. Is it possible to get the silverlight brushes colors in windowsphone. I am trying instead of using RGB color.

Here is my code to get System.Windows.Media.Color :

```
        Type t = typeof(System.Windows.Media.Color);
        PropertyInfo[] sysColors = t.GetProperties();
        foreach (var color in sysColors)
        {
           Color c = (Color)color.GetValue(null, null); 
        }
```

Comment: You mean System.Windows.Media.Colors .

Comment: [This](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/) book's page 658 might help.

Comment: I added System.Windows.Media.Color, I want to add some more colors within this. Is it possible?

Comment: To abhinav : book's page 658 is helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use System.Windows.Media.Colors class. It has more than 15 colors

Comment: Hi, i used System.Windows.Media.Colors it returns only 15 colors.